# PHP/HTML > Category instead of filename in url

Tags: php, html, url, categories

first I'll show you what I'm currently working with and then I'll show you what I would like to happen instead.

Homepage index.html contains a list of states, user clicks on the state and they are directed to cities.html in order to pick a city.  So we are now at http://www.example.com/cities.html?state=florida (or whatever).  Instead what I would like to see would be http://www.example.com/florida/

I know this is possible but I don't even know what to google for.  I've been trying variations  of "category instead of file url" and such on google and nothing has been remotely close.  Does anyone know how this is accomplished?  I know its possible as I've seen it in other places (that aren't using CMS).  One place I found using it was http://surgeonsdelivered.com/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What happens if you set the links on the home page to the format you require? Does it not work somehow?

Comment: If I set the links to http://www.example.com/iowa/ how would it know to go to the cities.html file versus any other file (such as help.html or any other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see. So you want all incoming requests for `http://www.example.com/xxxx/` to be processed as if they were `http://www.example.com/cities.html?state=xxxx` regardless of what `xxxx` may be.

If you are running on Apache then this can be accomplished with a `RewriteRule` using `mod_rewrite` in the `.htaccess` config file. A setting like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ /cities.html?state=$1
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like you are correct.  I'm trying to read about this now and wrap my head around it.  Do you happen to know what I would need for the RewriteRule to accomplish what I want here?  If not, no worries - would probably just save me an hour of head bumpin' ;)

Comment: Fantastic, I'll work with it from there, thanks again.  I'll check your response as soon as it allows me :)

Comment: I tried what you wrote but its not working.  Could it be because I also have a 301 Rewriterule in place in the .htaccess file thats messing it up?

Comment: Actually I took out the other rewrite stuff and it still doesn't work :\

Comment: Continued googling now that I know what to look for.  Was able to find the following:

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ cities.html?state=$1  And that has worked for the first part of what I need.

Comment: My guess is that you are working within a `<Directory>` rather than a `<VirtualHost>` entry, in which case there will be no leading slash on the path to be matched. Use a regex of `^([^/]+)/?$` instead.